# How to send data back to controller from model in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

I have getUsers() in Users controller like below

```
getUsers: function(req, res){       
  var results = User.getUsers();        
  return res.send(results);
}
```

I'm calling User Model's getUsers() method. Code for this method is below

```
getUsers: function(){
    User.find({}).exec(function findCB(err, found){       
       return found;
    });
}
```

Now how do I get this result(in this case 'found') back in the controller? So that I can send it to the front-end using response object.

It seems like these function calls are asynchronous..

Comment: Atleast have courage to post reason for downvoting. It can help us to learn something new....

Comment: As with a lot of downvotes - without an explanation it's meaningless - Upvoted as it's a valid question in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller would like as :

```
getUsers: function(req, res){       
                 User.getUsers(function (results) {
                    res.json(results);
                 });        
}
```

And model will be as :

```
getUsers: function(cb){
  User.find({}).exec(function(err, found){       
    if(err) // your error handling code 
    cb(found);
  });
}
```

cb is the callback function

- And yes "Fat model, skinny controller", is the good approach when following MVC

Comment: There is a fat model and then their is a bloated model. Why would you create the model method that the model already has and place that duplicate method in your controller instead using of the original method? While also you have not made your controller any skinnier by doing this. You still have to call the method on the model.

Comment: One of the reason for using database intearaction query in model is the reusability of code & also it affects the query optimization & so retain the concept of MVC.

Comment: Calling `User.find({})` from the controller directly still has all the benefits you mention. The model already is the separation you seek. Your answer simply wraps a function inside of another function inside the model and tells the controller to use that instead of the one that already exists. It duplicates the code, does not make the controller any smaller. It's the same if the model already had `add(x, y){return x + y)` and then you create another function that says `addNumbers(x,y){return add(x,y)}` and that he should call the second one from his controller instead of the first.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the main reasons to have getUsers function in model are : ** We have placed model interaction code in model as suggest by MVC pattern (as model manages the data). **  You can call this function from any controller so it supports reusability.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are creating the extra method inside your model. You can just access all users directly.

```
getUsers: function(req, res){       
  User.find().exec(function(results){
   return res.ok(results); 
  })        
}
```

Comment: I know controllers cab talk to database...But I have read many authors, and they say that your model(not the controller) should talk to database. "Fat model, skinny controller" concept also says that.

Comment: In that instance `User` is your model that is talking to the database.